# What is a Preprocessor Macros File in Eclipse CDT?

Tags: c, eclipse, macros, eclipse-cdt, c-preprocessor

In Eclipse CDT there is an entry type "Preprocessor Macros File" under Project Properties -> C/C++ General -> Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros, etc. -> Entries -> CDT User Setting Entries -> Add.

What is the purpose and format of such a file, in particular as opposed to a normal include file?

The Eclipse version is Luna Release (4.4.0) with CDT 8.4.0.

Comment: Consider not using Eclipse for compilation. Learn how to write your `Makefile`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I don't use Eclipse CDT for compilation, just for editing. Defines are still important, for example for not graying out #ifdef'd parts.

Comment: Then, edit your `Makefile` as you need.

Comment: Actually I'm asking more out of curiosity, to find out if it could be useful for anything.  I didn't find any documentation for it.

Comment: I would have loved to find an answer to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It allows you to tell Eclipse CDT to parse a C header file for defined preprocessor macros. For example to use GCC's C99 default preprocessor macros, without having to add them all individually, first generate the header file:

```
gcc -std=c99 -dM -E - < /dev/null > gccmacros_c.h
```

And then have Eclipse use that header file that was generated as a Preprocessor Macros File. I find this useful as a step when setting up Eclipse CDT's indexer to work properly with remote and cross compile C/C++ projects.

**Edit:** For more info see https://wiki.eclipse.org/HowTo_use_the_CDT_to_navigate_Linux_kernel_source and https://askubuntu.com/a/188127

Comment: Interesting, do you have a link to some documentation? What is allowed in such a file, just simple defines? Or can it handle more of the preprocessor syntax, for example `#ifdef`? Macros with parameters?

Comment: I learned about its purpose by reading [https://wiki.eclipse.org/HowTo_use_the_CDT_to_navigate_Linux_kernel_source] (tutorials) on using Eclipse to Navigate Linux kernel sources and one section of a tutorial talked about adding the kernel's [http://askubuntu.com/a/188127] (generated/autoconf.h file) via Preprocessor Macros File includes option. I have only used header files that have only #define and comments in them. So I don't know if a real preprocessor is involved parsing the file or not.

Comment: Yes, I also hate that, I always have to try all four permutations. I took the liberty to add the corrected links to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use project settings XML and add all the required macros there.
You can generate a base XML file by

```
Right Click on Project -> Go to properties -> C/C++ General -> Path and Symbol
```

and in `Symbol` tab, add some `pre-processor` for `GNU C` or `GNU C++` and export these settings as the file using "Export Setting" link at bottom of the window.
Then manually edit XML file for new macros and import using "import settings" button in above option.

Use saved file as the template for all other projects and import it once at the time of project creation.